# Sharepoint Client Object Model Updating Property of a only one folder

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-clientobject

I am working on a sharepoint clientobjectmodel code.
There is a folder called "John Details" inside "User Details Folder".
I am trying to update 2 properties for the "John Details" folder. 
How do I do that?

```
Public Void UpdateColumnsForOnlyOneFolder(maildId1,mailId2){
               ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("http://mytestsite/");

                List list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("User Details");
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
                ctx.Load(items); 
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();

                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    item["email1"] = mailId1;              
                    item["email2"] = mailId2;              
                    item.Update();
                }
                ctx.ExecuteQuery(); 
}
```

Comment: why a down arrow? Any mistake from my end?

Comment: Please try to re-frame your question. It is not understandable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your question properly, you would like to update the folder's associated list item properties. If so, you could consider the following approach:

- Get [Folder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.folder.aspx) by url using [Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.getfolderbyserverrelativeurl.aspx)
- Get *associated* [List Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listitem.aspx) using [Folder.ListItemAllFields property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.folder.listitemallfields.aspx)
- Update [List Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listitem.aspx) properties

**Example**

```
using (var ctx =  new ClientContext(webUri))
{
   var web = ctx.Web;

   var folder = web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl("/site/Documents/folder/sub folder");
   var listItem = folder.ListItemAllFields;
   listItem["PropertyName"] = "PropertyValue";
   listItem.Update();
   ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Comment: This property is an email id. Can we use this folder property to use for  share point notification?

Comment: A query - Normally the Folder content type is sealed by Microsoft. I am wondering if you have these email columns available to edit when you are using the browser ?

Comment: This will work only on Sharepoint 2013+ on 2010 ListItemAllFields is not exposed for folders.

Comment: This does not work for 2010. What changes I need to make in order to work with 2010?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that will update only the items of one folder

```html
Public Void UpdateColumnsForOnlyOneFolder(maildId1,mailId2){
               ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("http://mytestsite/");

                List list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("User Details");
         CamlQuery spQuery = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
                spQuery.FolderServerRelativeUrl = "Enter Relative URL TO FOLDER"  // Example "/managedpath/site/Lists/listname/Folder Name"
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(spQuery);
                ctx.Load(items); 
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();

                foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem item in items)
                {
                    item["email1"] = mailId1;              
                    item["email2"] = mailId2;              
                    item.Update();
                }
                ctx.ExecuteQuery(); 
}
```

Please mark as answer , if this works for you.